# Is there a way to dynamically apply the 'row-span-y' Tailwind CSS utility class based on a PHP variable in Laravel Blade?

Tags: php, laravel, tailwind-css, laravel-blade

I need to apply the `'row-span-y'` Tailwind CSS utility class on a div that is part of a `grid-layout` based on a PHP variable that has a value between 2 and 16, let's say.

So far, the only possible way that I've found that actually works is doing this:

```
$variable = 3;
switch ($variable) :
    case 2:
        echo '<div class="row-span-2">';
        break;
    case 3:
        echo '<div class="row-span-3">';
        break;
    case 4:
        echo '<div class="row-span-4">';
        break;
    case 5:
        echo '<div class="row-span-5">';
        break;
...
endswitch;

echo '</div>'
```

I don't want to do that. What I would like to do instead is:

```
$variable = 3;
echo '<div class="row-span-' . $variable . '"></div>';
```

But that doesn't seem to work with Tailwind CSS. The utility class is not recognized.

Comment: Cannot see why your prefered option would not work. Did you look at the generated HTML in the browser (View Page Source)

Comment: Cannot reproduce. See https://3v4l.org/qO0qn both generate the same output

Comment: That of course begs the question: Are you doing these 2 different things in the SAME location if the code

Comment: Probably I wasn't clear enough regarding if the HTML was correctly generated in both approaches or not. That wasn't the problem. The problem was that the rendered HTML was not making use of the row-span-y Tailwind CSS utility class correctly. In the first approach (switch based) the utility class was correctly detected and the row-span-3 did its job by rendering correctly the div. On the second approach, the utility class wasn't even detected at all (this was verified with the Chrome F12 tool) whenever I inspected the div with the row-span-3 class applied to it, like if it never existed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could consider using the `style` attribute, like:

```php
$variable = 3;
echo '<div style="grid-row: span ' . $variable . ' / span ' . $variable . ';"></div>';
```

Alternatively, since you seem to have knowledge of the exhaustive list of possible values, you could [`safelist` the classes](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#safelisting-classes), like:

```js
module.exports = {
  // …
  safelist: [
    { pattern: /^row-span-(1[0-6]|[2-9])$/ },
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      // Add extra row-span-* from 7 to 16 since they do not exist in the
      // default Tailwind configuration.
      gridRow: Object.fromEntries(
        Array(10).fill().map((_, i) => {
          const span = i + 7;
          return [
            `span-${span}`,
            `span ${span} / span ${span}`,
          ];
        }),
      ),
    },
  },
  // …
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. After you mentioned about safelisting the classes, I learnt about Tailwind CSS generates the utility classes based on the source code. That ended up fixing my problem. Thanks again.